# int на byte стоит ли?

Tags: java, переменные, byte, перевод, int

Говорят что все равно машина заменяет byte на int так как ей лучше работать с Int, если заменить все int на byte потребление ресурсов будет меньше ?

Comment: Не взеде. Массивы хранятся компактно, то есть байт там занимает байт. А переменные хранятся как инт и даже больше, так как ссылка только 64 бита будет занимать. Я думаю только для массивов есть смысл использовать байт

Comment: почитайте про выравнивание и регистры в процессоре, с точки зрения скорости разницы скорее всего не будет, а с точки зрения памяти это зависит от виртуальной машины

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko `А переменные хранятся как инт и даже больше, так как ссылка только 64 бита будет занимать` можете немного пояснить вашу мысль? Откуда там возникнет 64 бита (8 байт)?

Comment: То что 32 бита занимает занимает только значение числа int. Чтобы это число получить, нужна еще ссылка на память, где оно лежит. Для 32 битных систем размер ссылки равен 32 бита, для 64 - 64(возможно уменьшение до 32). То есть 32 + 64 бит

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko но ведь если у нас примитивный тип `int` будет частью класса, например, то на него не будет указателя, он будет лежать просто по определенному смещению от начала экземпляра класса, так?

Comment: Хммм. Не уверен. Звучит логично, но что-то мне пдсказывает, что все таки обычная ссылка

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko ну вот например накопал [`an instance with eight boolean fields will also take up 16 bytes: 8 for the header, 8 for the booleans; since this is already a multiple of 8, no padding is needed;`](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml), то есть на примитивные типы в этом случае не надо ссылок.

Comment: @tym32167 спс. Интересно. То есть, информация о самих полях, как их тип, тип досутпа и прочие модификаторы хранятся в самом описании класса, а не в каждом поле отдельно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандартном C/С++ никакая операция не может выполняться с типом меньше int. Если char, byty или short меньше, чем int на текущей платформе, они неявно повышаются до int. Компилятор должен сделать это неявное продвижение, там нет пути вокруг него, не нарушая стандарт.

Никакая операция с целочисленными значения (добавление, побитовое, логическое и т.д. и т.д.) в языке не может выполняться на меньшем целочисленном типе, чем int. Таким образом, операции с byte/char/short/int(и другими), как правило, одинаково быстры, так как первые повышаются до последнего.

На 32-битном процессоре, более мелкие типы медленнее, потому что он хочет, чтобы все было аккуратно выровнено в 32-битных кусках. 32-битные компиляторы обычно оптимизируют скорость и выделяют меньшие целые типы в большем пространстве, чем указано.

Хотя обычно меньшие целые типы, конечно, занимают меньше места, чем более крупные, поэтому, если вы планируете оптимизировать размер ОЗУ, то предпочительнее использовать, те типы в диапазон, которых входят значения.

Comment: Вопрос про Java

Comment: В Java аналогично. Принцып работы памяти один и тот же. И 32-битная система везде одинаковая. Приведен пример C, так как он более примитивный.

Comment: @КириллМалышев в Java под капотом Сишечка.